# Store a React useState array of objects in localStorage

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, local-storage

how can i store and get an array of objects useState in/from localStorage?  this current code is not working.

to be more specific, i would like the app to update the whole array of objects whenever certain values in it are changed (level, for example). it seems to be returning null as the level currently. would appreciate some help thanks!

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("symbolData", JSON.stringify(symbols));
  }, [currentSymbol.level]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const symbolData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("symbolData") || "[]");
    setSymbols(symbolData);
  }, []);
```

here's the structure of my array of objects

```
  const [symbols, setSymbols] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Vanishing Journey",
      alt: "Vanishing Journey Symbol",
      img: "/symbols/vj-symbol.webp",
      type: "arcane",
      dailyName: "Vanishing Journey Research",
      weeklyName: "Erda Spectrum",
      extraName: "Reverse City",
      level: NaN,
      experience: NaN,
      daily: NaN,
      weekly: NaN,
      extra: NaN,
      dailySymbols: 9,
      daysRemaining: 0,
      totalDaysRemaining: 0,
      symbolsRemaining: 0,
      mondayCount: 0,
      completion: "",
      data: [
        { level: 1, symbolsRequired: 0, mesosRequired: 0 },
        { level: 2, symbolsRequired: 12, mesosRequired: 7070000 },
        { level: 3, symbolsRequired: 15, mesosRequired: 11030000 },
        { level: 4, symbolsRequired: 20, mesosRequired: 14990000 },
        { level: 5, symbolsRequired: 27, mesosRequired: 18950000 },
        { level: 6, symbolsRequired: 36, mesosRequired: 22910000 },
        { level: 7, symbolsRequired: 47, mesosRequired: 26870000 },
        { level: 8, symbolsRequired: 60, mesosRequired: 30830000 },
        { level: 9, symbolsRequired: 75, mesosRequired: 34790000 },
        { level: 10, symbolsRequired: 92, mesosRequired: 38750000 },
        { level: 11, symbolsRequired: 111, mesosRequired: 42710000 },
        { level: 12, symbolsRequired: 132, mesosRequired: 46670000 },
        { level: 13, symbolsRequired: 155, mesosRequired: 50630000 },
        { level: 14, symbolsRequired: 180, mesosRequired: 54590000 },
        { level: 15, symbolsRequired: 207, mesosRequired: 58550000 },
        { level: 16, symbolsRequired: 236, mesosRequired: 62510000 },
        { level: 17, symbolsRequired: 267, mesosRequired: 66470000 },
        { level: 18, symbolsRequired: 300, mesosRequired: 70430000 },
        { level: 19, symbolsRequired: 335, mesosRequired: 74390000 },
        { level: 20, symbolsRequired: 372, mesosRequired: 78350000 },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Chu Chu Island",
      alt: "Chu Chu Symbol",
      img: "/symbols/chuchu-symbol.webp",
      type: "arcane",
      dailyName: "Chu Chu's Finest Cuisine",
      weeklyName: "Hungry Muto",
      extraName: "Yum Yum Island",
      level: NaN,
      experience: NaN,
      daily: localStorage.getItem("daily") === "true",
      weekly: localStorage.getItem("weekly") === "true",
      extra: localStorage.getItem("extra") === "true",
      dailySymbols: 8,
      daysRemaining: 0,
      totalDaysRemaining: 0,
      symbolsRemaining: 0,
      mondayCount: 0,
      completion: "",
      data: [
        { level: 1, symbolsRequired: 0, mesosRequired: 0 },
        { level: 2, symbolsRequired: 12, mesosRequired: 10840000 },
        { level: 3, symbolsRequired: 15, mesosRequired: 15460000 },
        { level: 4, symbolsRequired: 20, mesosRequired: 20080000 },
        { level: 5, symbolsRequired: 27, mesosRequired: 24700000 },
        { level: 6, symbolsRequired: 36, mesosRequired: 29320000 },
        { level: 7, symbolsRequired: 47, mesosRequired: 33940000 },
        { level: 8, symbolsRequired: 60, mesosRequired: 38560000 },
        { level: 9, symbolsRequired: 75, mesosRequired: 43180000 },
        { level: 10, symbolsRequired: 92, mesosRequired: 47800000 },
        { level: 11, symbolsRequired: 111, mesosRequired: 52420000 },
        { level: 12, symbolsRequired: 132, mesosRequired: 57040000 },
        { level: 13, symbolsRequired: 155, mesosRequired: 61660000 },
        { level: 14, symbolsRequired: 180, mesosRequired: 66280000 },
        { level: 15, symbolsRequired: 207, mesosRequired: 70900000 },
        { level: 16, symbolsRequired: 236, mesosRequired: 75520000 },
        { level: 17, symbolsRequired: 267, mesosRequired: 80140000 },
        { level: 18, symbolsRequired: 300, mesosRequired: 84760000 },
        { level: 19, symbolsRequired: 335, mesosRequired: 89380000 },
        { level: 20, symbolsRequired: 372, mesosRequired: 94000000 },
      ],
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Can you create a running demo using https://codesandbox.io/ to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that this line is correct

```js
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("symbolData", JSON.stringify(symbols));
  }, [currentSymbol.level]);
```

shouldn't it be Symbols rather than currentSymbol ?

Comment: yeah, i changed it to symbols but still sme problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect dependency array has a dependency for currentSymbol.level but I don't see that referenced in your effect and don't know how that variable is stored in your program. The dependency array from what I can see in the code you presented should have "symbols":

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("symbolData", JSON.stringify(symbols));
  }, [symbols]);
```

If you only want to listen for levels that maybe break that out into its own  state

Comment: i set it to symbols but it still does not persist anything when symbols is modified

Comment: where are you setting symbols? And when you do call setSymbols are you making it into the useEffect (just add a console.log to see if you reach there)? Could be something with your local storage being full?